# How to pass onComplete a variable containing a function name for Ajax class

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

Mootools Ajax class has a onComplete parameter whereby you can pass a function name to it and it would call that function when it completes (obvious).

http://docs111.mootools.net/Remote/Ajax.js

I want to be able to pass a variable containing the said function instead. How do I go about doing that? My attempt can be seen below.

```
/*
 * This way works
 */     
var TestClass = new Class({

    myRequest: function()
    {

        $aj = new Ajax(urle, {

          method: 'get',
          update: $('update_div'),
          onComplete: this.testFunctionA

        }).request();

    },

    testFunctionA: function()
    {
        alert('Yo');
    }

});

/*
 * This way doesn't 
 */     
var TestClass = new Class({

    myRequest: function()
    {

        var updateFunction = 'this.testFunctionA'; 

        $aj = new Ajax(urle, {

          method: 'get',
          update: $('update_div'),
          onComplete: updateFunction

        }).request();

    },

    testFunctionA: function()
    {
        alert('Yo');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `updateFunction` variable holds a string.

You need it to hold the function itself, like this:

```
var updateFunction = this.testFunctionA;
```

Comment: Magic. That worked! now waiting for SO to allow me to mark the answer

Comment: It's not magic.  It's just a variable that refers to a function.  It is very important to realize that Javascript functions are first-class objects that can be held in variables, etc.

Comment: me not knowing that fact makes it *magic*. thanks for your contribution